# Odoo Studio: I can't use domain in m2o field to hr.employee field

Tags: odoo-14

I'm using **Odoo Studio** to create a model that includes a m2o field to the employee model, and I need to set it's domain to an specific category.

1. I created an employee and I assigned the category "Operario"
   [image]
2. I created a new model in Odoo Studio with a m2o field to the hr.employee model and I added the next domain: [["category_ids.name","in","Operario"]]
   [image]
3. I tried to create a new registry in the new model but when I click on the o2m field I got this error if I'm not a member of the HR security group:

ValueError: Invalid field hr.employee.**public**.category_ids in leaf ('category_ids.name', 'in', 'Operario')

**Whole code:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch

    result = request.dispatch()

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/http.py", line 683, in dispatch

    result = self._call_function(**self.params)

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function

    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper

    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/http.py", line 347, in checked_call

    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/http.py", line 912, in __call__

    return self.method(*args, **kw)

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/http.py", line 531, in response_wrap

    response = f(*args, **kw)

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1377, in call_kw

    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1369, in _call_kw

    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/api.py", line 392, in call_kw

    result = _call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/api.py", line 365, in _call_kw_model

    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/models.py", line 1796, in name_search

    ids = self._name_search(name, args, operator, limit=limit)

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/models.py", line 1812, in _name_search

    return self._search(args, limit=limit, access_rights_uid=name_get_uid)

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/addons/hr/models/hr_employee.py", line 166, in _search

    ids = self.env['hr.employee.public']._search(args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, count=count, access_rights_uid=access_rights_uid)

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/models.py", line 4492, in _search

    query = self._where_calc(args)

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/models.py", line 4248, in _where_calc

    return expression.expression(domain, self).query

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/osv/expression.py", line 438, in __init__

    self.parse()

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/osv/expression.py", line 640, in parse

    raise ValueError("Invalid field %s.%s in leaf %s" % (model._name, path[0], str(leaf)))

Exception



The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception

    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)

  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/14.0/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception

    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause

ValueError: Invalid field hr.employee.public.category_ids in leaf ('category_ids.name', 'in', 'Operario')
```

In the last line of the error details, I see the word public, I'm not sure if that's a sub model, in any case I don't know where to setup those permissions for non HR members.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use `employee_id` instead of `category_ids` in the beginning. Because it is present in hr.employee table, not in hr.employee.public table.

Try this way,

```
[["employee_id.category_ids.name","=","Operario"]]
```

Also instead of `in` operator, use `=`, `like`, `ilike` for better integration with string type of value.

Comment: Thanks for your help,I tried but I got the next error, I think the problem is that Odoo Studio uses different access to the models attributes:

Error while validating view:
Unknown field "hr.employee.employee_id" in domain of <field name="x_studio_many2one_field_CDL9S"> '[["employee_id.category_ids.name","=","Operario"]]'
View name: Odoo Studio: Default form view for x_filtro_empleado customization
Error context:
 view: ir.ui.view(2845,)
 xmlid: studio_customization.odoo_studio_default__c6433747-da22-49db-a11e-88d987cb4981
 view.model: x_filtro_empleado
 view.parent: ir.ui.view(2843,)

Comment: You may accept this answer and ask new question with that details.